# i have a problem trying to install babel into my node.js project

Tags: node.js, npm

i am trying to run this command

`npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-env babel-watch`

and i am getting the following error

> npm ERR! code Z_BUF_ERROR 
>   npm ERR! errno -5
>   npm ERR! zlib: unexpected end of file

any help please or any other way i can use to install babel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing this (Clean Cache)

```
npm cache clean --force
```

before

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-env babel-watch
```

Comment: thanks again can u help me with this too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58275824/having-a-problem-with-setting-up-my-babel-watch-in-node-js