# having a problem with setting up my babel-watch in node.js

Tags: npm

I am trying to install babel watch after I have installed babel
my json file is as follows

```json
{
  "name": "t3",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "babel server.js --out-dir build",
    "dev-start": "babel-watch server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-watch": "^7.0.0"
  }
}
```

but i am getting this error while running
`npm run dev-start`

> t3@1.0.0 dev-start C:\Users\PRO\Desktop\t3
> babel-watch server.js

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
> throw err;
> ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
> at Object. (C:\Users\PRO\Desktop\t3\node_modules\babel-watch\babel-watch.js:7:15)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! t3@1.0.0 dev-start:
> `babel-watch server.js` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR!
> Failed at the t3@1.0.0 dev-start script. npm ERR! This is probably not
> a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Answer (score 0):

[Update]
You might have update the babel. check out https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8908 & [How to upgrade to babel 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52157996/how-to-upgrade-to-babel-7)

Try

```
npm install @babel/core --save
```

Comment: @LeonardHABIMANA post it here

Comment: this error ```> babel-watch server.js

Babel compilation error TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null```

Comment: you might have update the babel. check out https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8908 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52157996/how-to-upgrade-to-babel-7